# Command nesting in VSTS/TFS

Tags: docker, tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to run the following nested command on VSTS using linux shell and Docker, so I can stop and remove all the containers that are based on the "jspsample" image:

```
docker rm $(docker stop $(docker ps -a -q --filter ancestor=jspsample --format="{{.ID}}"))
```

[image]

Unfortunately the agent always returns the following error code:

```
2017-01-31T12:06:22.0585100Z unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a

2017-01-31T12:06:22.0636870Z See 'docker stop --help'.

2017-01-31T12:06:22.0827520Z ##[error]/usr/bin/docker failed with return code: 125

2017-01-31T12:06:22.0850140Z ##[error]/usr/bin/docker failed with error: /usr/bin/docker failed with return code: 125
```

Is there a way to run this nested command, or do I need to run a shell script?

Comment: What's the result if you run that nested command on build agent machine manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Command Line" task does not support command nesting. Save your command as a shell script and upload to code repository and then use "Shell Script" task to run the script.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue when I tried to clean up images on a nightly build. Basically this command:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -aq)
```

So I created a pull request for the Docker VSTS task to include an output variable to store the output of the Docker command: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-docker/pull/44

For more details about my investigation into this issue, see my StackOverflow post: [Removing unused docker images on a remote Linux Azure hosted docker instance gives 'unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -aq' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42853895/removing-unused-docker-images-on-a-remote-linux-azure-hosted-docker-instance-giv)